# macro excel file not showing code when send vial email

Tags: excel, vba

i have a question about macro excel file .

Iam using vba in macro excel and it working fine but when i send it via email to another user to use , it shows empty code .
I saved it in .xlsm but still showing empty code

can someone tell me why??

Comment: I think most email clients even block .xlsm files completely. You better find another way of sharing your excel file.

Comment: Does the other user open the file in Excel  desktop application? Excel online or Google Spreadsheets don't read code., after all. Also, try to send the file zipped as rar with password. And I guess both users got Windows?

Answer (score 0):

The Person Receiving the Email has to have Macros enabled in excel as well

Comment: the person who received did enable it but still not working